# OpenApi Spring generator - missing model files

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I can sucessfully generate Spring API and model files using gradle, OpenApi generator plugin (`"org.openapi.generator" version "4.2.1"`).

I have a single `api.yml` file:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: API Documentation
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080/
tags:
  - name: Users
paths:
  /users:
    post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
      responses:
        200:
          description: New user created

components:
  schemas:

    Parent:
      required:
        - status
      properties:
        status:
          type: string
      discriminator:
        propertyName: status
        mapping:
          CHILD_ONE: '#/components/schemas/ChildOne'
          CHILD_TWO: '#/components/schemas/ChildTwo'

    ChildOne:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
        - type: object

    ChildTwo:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
        - type: object
```

And code generation produces Java Spring interface file and 3 model files: `Parent.java`, `ChildOne.java` and `ChildTwo.java` - 2 children classes  extend the `Parent` class as expected.

**However**, when I split `api.yml` into 2 files (see below), `ChildOne.java` and `ChildTwo.java` are completely missing (there is only `Parent.java` file generated):

`api.yml` file:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: API Documentation
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080/
paths:
  /users:
    $ref: './api-sub.yml#/test'
```

api-sub.yml file:

```
test:
   post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
      responses:
        200:
          description: New user created

components:
  schemas:
    Parent:

      required:
        - status
      properties:
        status:
          type: string
      discriminator:
        propertyName: status
        mapping:
          CHILD_ONE: '#/components/schemas/ChildOne'
          CHILD_TWO: '#/components/schemas/ChildTwo'

    ChildOne:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
        - type: object

    ChildTwo:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
        - type: object
```

Generation passes without errors but only 1 class - `Parent.java` is generated:

```
// [...]
// Imports etc....
// [...]

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "status", visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildOne.class, name = "CHILD_ONE"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildTwo.class, name = "CHILD_TWO"),
})

public class Parent   {
  @JsonProperty("status")
  private String status;

// [...]
// Getters, setters etc....
// [...]
```

**Why 2 other classes `ChildOne.java` and `ChildTwo.java` are not generated?**

Please note that generator is seeing them as it uses their names and mappings in `Parent.java`.

I did some investigations and I've noticed that when I move schema definitions from `api-sub.yml` into `api.yml` like this:

`api.yml` file:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: API Documentation
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080/
paths:
  /users:
    $ref: './api-sub.yml#/test'

components:
  schemas:

    Parent:
      required:
        - status
      properties:
        status:
          type: string
      discriminator:
        propertyName: status
        mapping:
          CHILD_ONE: '#/components/schemas/ChildOne'
          CHILD_TWO: '#/components/schemas/ChildTwo'

    ChildOne:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
        - type: object

    ChildTwo:
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
        - type: object
```

`api-sub.yml` file:

```
test:
   post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: 'api.yml#/components/schemas/Parent'
      responses:
        200:
          description: New user created
```

Then, 4 files are generated: `Parent.java`, `ChildOne.java`, `ChildTwo.java` and (surprise) `Parent2.java`.

`Parent2.java` is semantically the same as `Parent.java`, just different name.

Any idea why is it so?
Is there are bug in OpenApi generator?

**Edit:**

Yet another observation:

When I use a child somewhere in any endpoint e.g. (just for testing) in response, then this particular child is generated (but not the other one):

```
test:
   post:
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/Parent'
      responses:
        200:
          description: New user created
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ChildOne'

### [...]
### rest of api-sub.yml with schemas
### [...]
```

Does the child entity needs to be used to be generated? I've noticed such a behavior somewhere else beside of inheritance case.

Comment: Looks like a codegen bug. Please open an issue at https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues

Comment: @Helen Done https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4710